# Is there a reason why System dll is different in Silverlight and other C# Libraries

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

The reason I am asking is because I wrote an extension method to use in Silverlight only to find out that feature magically started working for silver light.

Example

```
string sentence = "I am a sentence that has some words";
sentence.Contains("N"); //would return false, silverlight true
sentence.Contains("n"); //would return true, silverlight true
```

Why is there a special System dll in the framework for Silverlight that does the comparsion as case insenstive?

I have run into this for tons of methods, it's kind of annoying that they either act different or are just missing in general.

Comment: I am mostly irritated that there are crazy differences in System between say:

c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\Silverlight\v4.0\system.dll

C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\System.dll

They are both System and System.String.Contains() acts different, it's more of an annoyance than anything but I keep running into little things like this.

Comment: I've just tested that on a standard Silverlight project; it returned `false` as expected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The reason I am asking is because I wrote an extension method to use in Silverlight only to find out that feature magically started working for silver light.

There is a `public bool string.Contains(string)` method for all versions of .NET from 2.0 onwards ([2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa%28v=VS.80%29.aspx), [3.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), [3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa%28v=VS.90%29.aspx), [4.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), [SL 3/4 WP 7.0/7.1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)).

It is interesting to note that the SL version is only listed from SL 3 / 4 - ***is it possible you updated from a 2.0 solution?*** That *could* then account for it.

Otherwise, a defined method always takes precedence over an extension method, so your extension method should never be called (we can exclude .NET 1.1 since the C# 1.2 compiler does not include extension methods).

For .NET 2.0 MSDN documents this as:

> This method performs a word (case-sensitive and culture-sensitive) search using the current culture. The search begins at the first character position of this string and continues through the last character position.

All other versions (including Silverlight)  are listed as:

> This method performs an ordinal (case-sensitive and culture-insensitive) comparison. The search begins at the first character position of this string and continues through the last character position.

If you are seeing otherwise (please treble-check), it *could* be a framework error... but I'm cautiously expecting a simpler explanation.

Comment: Yeah I saw that it started in versions 3 & 4.  But I guess my question is just more why did they not give .Contains the same insensitivity to the non-silverlight version to keep it consistent?

Comment: @Cubicle er... they did? at least that is what MSDN states.

Comment: @Cubicle I clarified the MSDN quotes; in .NET 2.0 it is case-sensitive, culture-sensitive; in **everything else** it is case-sensitive, culture-insensitive. So either way, it should be case-sensitive